# Spring - MongoDB

Tags: java, database, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Intellij doesn't recognize mongodb annotations. this is my pom.xml file :

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.notification</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>notification</name>
<description>somestuf</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[this is how it looks from intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpWP4.png)

Any suggestions what is causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your `pom.xml` - it works fine in my sample project. Looks like some issues with dependencies. Try "Reimport Maven dependencies" (project - right click - Maven - Reimport)

Comment: What OS you have installed, Mongo version and what do you use for spring please ?

Comment: Details may help

Comment: For compiling Spring application you don't need Mongo to be installed. Annotation is located in dependency called org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.0.9.RELEASE (using your versions in Maven). So if you are using Idea you should see this dependency in "External Libraries" in any OS.

Comment: Used that dependency , did the reimport still it does not remove the error

Comment: is it building if you execute 'mvn clean install' in the terminal in project directory?

Comment: i included as an external package the 2.0.9 version and it recognizes the annotations
But it gives me this error

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration.mongoTemplate

Comment: have no idea, looks like you have some dependencies issues, is this example working in your IDE https://github.com/nazar-mykolyshyn/demo-mongo ?